# Is there a way to use a different image for each side of a CSS3 border-image?

Tags: image, border, css

On Firefox and Safari, I can use an image for the border with the following CSS:

```
-moz-border-image: url(shadow_left.png) 0 7 0 7 round round;
-webkit-border-image: url(shadow_left.png) 0 7 0 7 round round;
```

However, I can't figure out a way to use a different image for left and right. Is there any way of doing so which is supported by modern browsers?

Comment: does url accept strings without being wrapped in single quotes?  I've only ever seen url(shadow_left.png) written as url('shadow_left.png')

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Previous drafts said [it's possible](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#border-images), by using:

```
border-top-image
border-right-image
border-bottom-image
border-left-image
border-top-left-image
border-top-right-image
border-bottom-left-image
border-bottom-right-image
```

[image]

However, the [current candidate recommendation for CSS Backgrounds and Borders](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#border-images)(25 November 2009) these properties disappeared. It looks like you cannot use different images for each border side anymore.

As a personal note, I wouldn't have used different images anyway to avoid flickering for the same reason one would pack button states (unpressed, pressed, hover) in a single image file and then use css to offset in the source image.

EDIT: `border-top-image`, `border-left-image`, etc were present in [WD 2002-11-07](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/) but disappeared in [WD 2005-02-16](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/).

EDIT2: You might be interested in the [jquery.borderimage.js](http://www.lrbabe.com/sdoms/borderImage/index.html#bi) plugin.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 allows `border-left-image` (and top, right, bottom) I would expect the browser-specific versions to do the same. But didn't test it.

Comment: Tried that, no dice in either browser. Tried lots of syntax variations on -moz-border-image-right: url(/images/shadow_r.png) 7px round;

Answer (score 2):

Reading [the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images), there does not seem to be any mention of using different borders for the different edges. However, [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) mentions a few properties that should exist, but doesn't according to the spec.